# A Question on Integrals and Limits

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm in trouble to show the following:

Let $\phi(s)\in C^\infty(0,\infty)$ such that $0\le \phi(s)\le 1$ and $\phi(s)=1 (s\ge 1)$, $\phi(s)=0(s\le 1/2)$. Let $x = (x_1, x_2)$, $\psi(x)\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ and $\psi(x_1, 0)=0$. Then I want to show that for any $u\in L^p((\mathbb R \times (0,\infty))$, 
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{\partial\phi(x_2/\epsilon)}{\partial x_2} \psi(x) u(x) dx_1 dx_2 \to 0 \quad (\epsilon \to 0).
$$
Here $C_c^\infty$ means $C^\infty$ class with compact support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First notice that the pointwise limit of the integrand is $0$. Indeed, fix $x \in \mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)$ and let $\epsilon$ be so small that $x_2/\epsilon > 1$. Now recall that since $\phi$ is constant for $s \ge 1$ its derivative is $0$ for $s > 1$.

What we are left to prove is that we can pass the limit inside the integral signs. By Lebesgue's dominated convergence Theorem, it is enough to show that the integrand is dominated by an integrable function.

This is easy: by assumption, $\phi'$ is continuous and $0$ outside the compact set $[1/2,1]$, hence it is bounded. Notice also that $u \in L^1(\text{supp}(\psi))$. Then we have $$|\phi'(x_2/\epsilon)\psi(x)u(x)| \le \big(\|\phi'\|_{L^\infty}\|\psi\|_{L^\infty}\big)\chi_{\text{supp}(\psi)}(x)u(x) \in L^1(\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)).$$

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. But I could not understand that $u\in L^1(supp \psi)$, because $u$ is just in $L^p$ for some $p\ge 1$. Would you provide some more detail of this? Thanks

Comment: @Keverta: the support of $\psi$ is compact and hence bounded. This in particular implies that it has finite measure. Now recall that for sets of finite measure we have the inclusion $L^p \subset L^1$.

Comment: oh i missed it thanks!